# folium choropleth tuning the legend of map

Tags: legend, folium, choropleth

- I just wanna ask how to change the legend of the folium-generated map to a correct scale and color?

```
state_data = pd.read_csv(r'D:\BaiduNetdiskDownload\US_folium\china-population.csv')

max_value = state_data['population'].max()
state_data['population'] /= max_value
bins = list(state_data['population'].quantile([i/10 for i in range(0, 11)]))


m = folium.Map(location=[37, 108], zoom_start=4)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=r'D:\BaiduNetdiskDownload\US_folium\china-counties.json',
    data=state_data,
    columns=["county", "population"],
    key_on="feature.id",
    fill_color="BuPu",
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.1,
    legend_name="人口数量",
    bins=bins,
    reset=True,
).add_to(m)
```

and the `bins` restricted the value to 0~1.0. and it shows the population of every block on the map. the population ranges from 2300 ~12042384.
[image]

Comment: Your `bins` value is bad, the last interval is so large, causing very long last (black) color segment. Try simple quartile bins: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0] first, then increase steps as needed.

Comment: the problem is that the data is correct and the legend does not support the `log(data)` function to smoothing.